# Custom non-template page on front end fails to render

Tags: plugin-development, pages

I added a link to a custom page on the front end like so:

```
function renderCheckoutLink($links) {
  $links .= "<li><a href='tradeIns'>Trade Ins</a></li>";

  return $links;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'renderCheckoutLink');
```

This page should have the default wordpress header/footer but a custom content area. I think because it is a one off, a template is not needed for it. I tried to create it following the first reply in this SO topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528391/wordpress-plugin-add-page-frontend

```
function createCheckoutPage() {
  if (is_page('tradeIns')) { 
    $pagePath = VIEWS_PATH . '/checkout.php';
    require_once($pagePath);
  }
}
add_action('wp', 'createCheckoutPage');

// Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I do not see any requests in the network tab to try to load my view file. What mistake am I making above?

**Also tried**

Using the hook `the_content`. Same result

Comment: The first [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35303633) (which uses the `wp` hook) includes a `die();`

Comment: @SallyCJ Ok, with `die()` the red console error is gone but the page still doesn't render. In the browser I see this: `Oops! That page can’t be found.
Nothing was found at this location. Try searching, or check out the links below.`

Comment: What's in your `checkout.php`? Try adding `var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp'], $GLOBALS['wp_query'] );` and inspect the query, etc. But actually, if you don't want to set `checkout.php` as a custom Page template, then try the [`page_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/) filter to force WordPress to load that `checkout.php` file as the page template.

Comment: Actually, if `tradeIns` is not a WordPress page or that the path doesn't exist, then when using the `wp` hook, you should send a `400` ("OK") HTTP status header - e.g. using `status_header( 200 );` as in my [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/349867/137402).