# add_rewrite_rule: Issue converting path to url

Tags: pages, url-rewriting

I would like my plugin to route /tradeIns for any domain it's installed on to the template file inside the plugin filder's `templates/checkout.php`. In my local dev site the desired url route would be `http://localhost/wptest2/tradeIns`

Attempting to use `add_rewrite_rule()` I have written this:

```
function addCheckoutRedirect() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^tradeIns'
    , 'localhost/wptest2/wp-content/plugins/pluginNake/templates/checkout.php'
    ,'top'
  );
}
add_action('init', 'addCheckoutRedirect', 10, 0);
```

This is a copy/paste modification of the "non index.php" example at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

I'm getting an `Oops, page not found` error on my test site. It could be the regex match.

I suspect it may be the hardcoded path string in the 2nd argument above. I switched `/var/html/www/wptest2/` to `localhost/wptest2/` which is the path-to-url difference for other pages like the home page, but it may not be working here.

Can someone advise me on the correct way to write the rewrite url here (statically or dynamically)? Or if the regex is the actual issue I'd appreciate any feedback on that too, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should just start with `wp-content` because the generated rewrite rule (which would be added to your `.htaccess`) is relative to your WordPress installation directory:

```php
function addCheckoutRedirect() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'tradeIns', // I intentionally removed the caret (^)
        'wp-content/plugins/pluginNake/templates/checkout.php',
        'top'
    );
}
```

And here's how your `.htaccess` file may look like after the addition of the above "non `index.php`" rule: (in this example, WordPress is installed in the root directory; hence the `RewriteBase` is `/`)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# WordPress automatically added the caret (^), and the slash (/) before wp-content
RewriteRule ^tradeIns /wp-content/plugins/pluginNake/templates/checkout.php [QSA,L]
...
# END WordPress
```

Don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings page.

### Alternate Option

Create a standard Page (post of the `page` type), give it the slug `tradeIns` and use the [`page_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/) hook to load the `checkout.php` page when the `tradeIns` page is being requested.

```php
add_filter( 'page_template', function ( $template ) {
    return is_page( 'tradeIns' )
        ? '/full/path/to/plugins/pluginNake/templates/checkout.php'
        : $template;
} );
```

Using this option gives you the advantage that you don't need any custom rewrite rules or the need to set your plugin's `checkout.php` as a custom Page template.

But the final decision is yours; just use whichever option is best for your specific needs.

### Another Option: Completely Dynamic URL

Which means you don't need any custom rewrite rules and no need to create any Pages.

And this example uses the [`parse_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) hook, but you may also use the `wp` hook or a similar hook. However, when using the `wp` hook (or any hooks where WordPress already sent the headers), you would want to call `status_header( 200 );` to announce a `200` HTTP status header. And that is to prevent a "not found"/`404` error since the path (`tradeIns` in the example below) doesn't actually exist (not a WordPress Page, etc.).

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', function ( $wp ) {
    if ( 'tradeIns' === $wp->request ) { // the request is example.com/tradeIns
        //status_header( 200 );
        require_once '/full/path/to/plugins/pluginNake/templates/checkout.php';
        exit;
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you, I am investigating a plugin-only way to implement your alternate suggestion. `insert_post()` may be able to do it. Do you know how to set the post content to a `require_once` on a `.php` template file? That is my current snag.

Comment: I don't really understand that.. perhaps you can post another question and clarify what you mean? But yes, plugins can use `wp_insert_post()` to programmatically create new Pages/posts.